# Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: C:\android-ndk/jni /Android.mk

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I am trying to compile an android NDK project I am getting the following error:

```
Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: C:\android-ndk/jni/Android.mk
c:/android-ndk/build/core/add-application.mk:187: *** Android NDK: Aborting...
Stop.
```

Here is my android.mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := bullet
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := bullet.cpp control.cpp
LOCAL_ARM_MODE   := arm
BULLET_HOME = ../BulletAndroid-2.78
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -O3 -DANDROID_NDK -DDISABLE_IMPORTGL -I $(BULLET_HOME)/jni/Bullet -I             $(BULLET_HOME)/jni/Irrlicht/include -I $(BULLET_HOME)/jni/irrBullet 

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L $(BULLET_HOME)/libs/armeabi -lGLESv1_CM -ldl -llog -lGLESv2 -lirrlichtbullet  

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And here is my application.mk file

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
APP_STL := stlport_static
APP_PROJECT_PATH := D:\Work\Projects\NDK-Examples\ca.renzhi.bullet
```

Why this error is there... I have set the path of ndk at eclipse as well as in environment variable

Comment: you need to run ndk-build from within the project directory

Comment: solved the problem error while setting environment variable..

Answer (score 2):

The result is because you haven't set NDK_PROJECT_PATH to the parent directory of "jni" in your project.

For example, in my project directory, I use:

```
export NDK_PROJECT_PATH=`pwd`
```

And compilation works fine.

Comment: Can you elaborate this a bit more? where to set this?

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice you were using Windows. This command line will export an environment key called NDK_PROJECT_PATH and assign it with the value of the current directory. Just make sure you have SET NDK_PROJECT_PATH="c:/

Answer (score 0):

***C:\android-ndk/jni /Android.mk***

Be careful, there is a ***blank*** in jni folder , please remove it again.